# Nestjs with Neo4j graphQL library causing RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: neo4j, nestjs

I am trying to learn a new concept for myself - Graph databases.

I also decided to try out GraphQL with it.
Learning two new technologies... What possibly could go wrong??!?!?

I created a wee apollo+neo4j+neo4j-graphql library project and it works. I could make custom resolvers, the data saves to the DB...everything works great.

So I decided to add a structure to this wee project and what is better than Angular structure, right? So.. . I found Nest JS.

My question is... How do you marry NestJs with Neo4j-graphQL library?

I just keep getting:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

With this code

```
const driver = neo4j.driver(
  "bolt://localhost:7687",
  neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "Qwertyui1!")
);
const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({
  typeDefs,
  driver,

  config: {
    jwt: {
      secret: "secret"
    }
  }
});

let graphSchema: GraphQLSchema = neoSchema.schema;
console.error(graphSchema);
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({

      playground: false,
      plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault()],
      debug: false,
      disableHealthCheck: true,
      //  typePaths: ['./models/*.graphql'],
      definitions: {
        path: null
      },
      schema: graphSchema

    })
  ],
```

Here is the source code:
https://github.com/mcgri/neo4jWithNestjs